# fatalAssertNotError-like-method in MATLAB unit test

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am writing a class-based test suite in MATLAB for a timeseries handling package. The first test in my suite needs to check whether a connection exists to a Haver database on a network drive. If the connection does not exist, then the first test should abort the rest of the suite using one of the `fatalAssert` methods.

One complicating factor, which I have excluded from the exposition below, but I will mention now is that I need to use an anonymous function to check the connection to Haver (unless someone has a better idea). My package handles data from multiple sources, Haver only being one of them.

I have a parent-class test suite that performs general tests for all of the sources. I then inherit this parent-class into specific child-class test suites and set specific parameters in their respective `TestMethodSetup` method. One of these parameters is an anonymous function, `connfun`, and a location, `connloc`, which I use in the parent-class to test the connection. The reason I do this is because the parent tests are executed first, so I would have to wait for all of those to end if I wanted to test the connection in the child class.

This also complicates the order of execution. If I want to assign the `connfun` in the child class, then I have to use either the `TestMethodSetup` or `TestClassSetup` of the child class (open to recommendations on which is best here) and put this connection test in the `Test` method of the parent class. I noticed the if I put `checkConn` in the `TestMethodSetup` and `TestClassSetup` of the parent class was running before that of the child class, I was unable to pass the anonymous function and the test would be incomplete.

Putting the previous point aside for a moment, this was my first attempt at writing the test in the parent-class (note that I used a `fatalAssertEqual` instead of a `fatalAssertTrue` because `isconnection()` does not return a logical):

```matlab
methods (Test)
    function checkConn(testCase)
        connloc = 'pathToHaverDatabase';
        connfun = @(x) isconnection(haver(x));
        testCase.fatalAssertEqual(connfun(connloc), 1);
    end
end
```

The above works when there is a connection, but the problem that I bumped into with this is that when I cannot access `connloc`, an error ocurrs during the call to `haver()`. So instead of returning a 1 or 0 from the `isconnection()` call that I can `fatalAssertEqual` on, all of `checkConn` errors out due to `haver()`. This then leads to the rest of the tests running (and failing, which is exactly what I want to avoid).

My next idea works for both cases, but it *feels* like bad code, and **does not** have the anonymous function specification described above.

```matlab
methods (Test)
    function checkConn(testCase)
        connloc = 'pathToHaverDatabase';
        connfun = @(x) isconnection(haver(x));
        try
            isconn = connfun(connloc);
        catch
            isconn = 0;
        end
        testCase.fatalAssertEqual(isconn, 1)
    end
end
```

When I wrote this, I did not necessarily want to distinguish between not having access to the network drive, not being able to call the `haver()` function, and getting an `isconnection` equal to 0 because the last case covers all three. But I realized that if I did differentiate them, then it would be a bit more robust, but it's still missing the anonymous function taht I could pass from child to parent.

```matlab
properties
    connloc = 'pathToHaverDatabase';
end

methods (Test)

    function checkDrive(testCase)
        isfound = fillattrib(testCase.connloc);
        testCase.fatalAssertTrue(isfound);
    end

    function checkHaver(testCase)
        try
            hav = haver(testCase.connloc);
            ishaver = ~isempty(hav);
        catch
            ishaver = false;
        end
        testCase.fatalAssertTrue(ishaver);
    end

    function checkConn(testCase)
        connfun = @(x) isconnection(haver(x));
        testCase.fatalAssertEqual(connfun(testCase.connloc), 1);
    end 
end
```

Ideally, what I would want is a `fatalAssert` method (or something similar) that ends the test suite when its input is an error. Something that would perhaps be called `fatalAssertNotError`, but I don't think that exists. If it did, the last line of my first function would simply be `testCase.fatalAssertNotError(connfun(connloc))` and I would not have to worry about all the cases.

I'm very open to dynamic rewrite of this whole test setup, so any specific comments or general advice are welcome!

Comment: Why must it be an anonymous function? Can’t it be a subfunction that you take a handle from?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an anonymous function, that's just my initial inclination. I'm not sure that a subfunction is the right call in the class-based unit-testing framework though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think the fatalAssert case is a strong use case to provide something like fatalAssertNotError. One reason why it is not part of the package is because many/most times people don't want to check whether something doesn't error, they just want to call the code, and if it errors, it fails for the test author automatically and it is much simpler. However, other qualification types like fatal assertions and assumptions perhaps point to the need to provide this so you can choose the outcome of the test in the presence of an error, in cases where you don't want it to fail (like with assumptions) or you want it to fail "more strongly" like with fatal assertions.

That being said, I am still not convinced that you can't achieve what you are ultimately trying to do without it. The question I have centers around why you can't use `TestClassSetup`. It is not clear to me exactly why you weren't able to customize in the derived test class to get the behavior you want. For example, does something like this work?

```
classdef BaseTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    properties(Abstract)
        connloc
        connfun
    end
    methods(TestClassSetup)
        function validateConnection(testCase)
            % If this errors it behaves like an assertion (not fatal assertion)
            % and fails all tests in the test class. If it doesn't error but
            % doesn't return 1 then the assertion failure will occur.
            testCase.assertEqual(connfun(connloc), 1, 
                'Could not establish a connection to the database'); 
        end
    end
end

classdef DerivedTest < BaseTest
    properties
        connloc = 'pathToHaverDatabase';
        connfun = @(x) isconnection(haver(x));
    end
    methods(Test)
        function testSomething(testCase)
            % Have at least one test method to test it out
        end
    end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Andy, extremely delayed response; I never hit submit when I wrote up this comments months ago. I ended up using your suggestions above and refined the code. I realize that my structure was greatly improved by that, but I do still think a `fatalAssertNotError` would be a great addition. I will often have colleagues say that all tests are failing, but it's just because they are not connected to a network drive. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a function you can define a nested one like this:

```matlab
methods (Test)
  function checkConn(testCase)
    connloc = 'pathToHaverDatabase';
    function res = connfun(x)
      try
        res = isconnection(haver(x));
      catch
        res = false
      end
    end
    testCase.fatalAssertEqual(connfun(connloc), 1);
  end
end
```

Nested functions can be a bit confusing to me because of the way they share data with the parent function. There really is no difference between an anonymous function and a nested function.

The alternative is to put the function at the end of the file, outside the `classdef` block:

```matlab
classdef ...
%...
methods (Test)
  function checkConn(testCase)
    connloc = 'pathToHaverDatabase';
    function res = connfun(x)
      try
        res = isconnection(haver(x));
      catch
        res = false
      end
    end
    testCase.fatalAssertEqual(connfun(connloc), 1);
  end
end
%...
end

function res = connfun(x)
  try
    res = isconnection(haver(x));
  catch
    res = false
  end
end
```

But I honestly don't understand why you need to have a function call within `fatalAssertEqual`. The code you have seems perfectly fine to me.